# Merging resources into reference-request

Tags: discussion, tags

I guess there are not a lot of uses for [resources](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) and it is currently only used three times. Basically all of these questions were asking for some kind of reference and I think the [reference-request](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) would still be appropriate. Even there are not a lot of questions.

There is also no tag wiki for resources, so the scope is yet undefined. One could append the reference-request to include resources:

> This tag is for questions looking for a single specific, or a small number of (citable) references. *It may also be applied to questions looking for (online) resources and/or materials.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have freed the world of [resources](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources), as I don't think it serves any distinct purpose.  I won't go so far as to blacklist it, since it could be used in the future as a synonym for "natural resources" or something of that nature.

I would go so far as to say that we should remove the "*It may also be applied to questions looking for (online) resources...*" portion since most answers needing evidence are going to link to some sort of online reference or another, or might even be too broad if there are too many resources available.