# Can we please burninate the organic tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

It was created recently and (fortunately) hasn't been used till now.

- It is pointless, unless somebody wants to advertise home-grown lettuce on Chemistry.SE!
- It is ugly and I do **not** want to use it as a synonym for [organic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-chemistry)!

Can we please just let it die and make sure that it never appears again?

Comment: I wonder how tags are created without it being used in any questions. Maybe the question that used it got deleted.

Comment: I changed it to the standard lingo on SE.  We will run this by a CM once there is enough support.  I, for one, agree.

Comment: (as it stands, the orphaned one will be deleted automatically since it's no longer on any questions)

Comment: I'm not very sure what happened this time @user223679, but this could be true too: A user suggests an edit, and introduces a new tag in the tags. That way, user community creates the tag, no matter the edit is rejected or not.

Comment: @jonsca What is the status on the ban of the tag?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I can check into it further.  Has it been remade?  (I honestly didn't look)

Comment: @jonsca No, I was just checking ;)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I haven't forgotten about this, I was thinking I would keep an eye on it for a bit before making a move to the CMs.

Comment: @jonsca No worries. Next time the tag shows up this post will probably automatically reactivate, so for the time being just enjoy a `organic` free life...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tag was on the question "Photoisomerization of Azobenzene", see the edit history [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/31730/revisions).

I am responsible for making this tag an orphan, meaning as soon as I saw it, I substituted it to the proper tag. I do things like this at least once a week and I outlined the procedure [somewhere on meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1651/4945) before. Unused, they are called orphaned, tags will be removed from the register. And if you go to the tags page, you won't be able to find it any more. Unfortunately I cannot remember where it says, when they are cleared, but I think it was 03:00 UTC. The [help centre](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) does not mention it, maybe the faq would - and it does: [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/260760)

I remember, that this was not the first time I burned that particular tag and I am very much pro banning it. It's just like fighting the title buzzwords, you have to keep hunting them down. I admit it's a lot easier with tags.

Answer (score 6):

## Update (11/7/2019)

After the tag reappeared somewhat recently, we have decided to finally contact the team about blacklisting it. You can follow our process in the Spring Cleaning Chat, [2019/7/9 - 7/11](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/55978/2019/7/9).

Comment: Update: Tis done as requested

Comment: Thank you @CesarM!